# Number of involutions in a finite group

Tags: finite-groups

It is easy to see that the number of involutions in an elementary abelian $2$-group of finite rank $n$ is $2^n-1$. Is there a formular for computing the number of involutions in any finite abelian group or precisely, is there any bound on the number of involutions in finite abelian groups $G$ in terms of $|G|$?

Comment: In particular, I am interested in knowing whether we have any good bound on the proportion of involutions in an arbitrary abelian group of order n which is non-cyclic?